# Scroll to top and then go back On Back Button Pressed in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a [recyclerveiw](/questions/tagged/recyclerveiw). When user press back i want recyclerview to scroll to top. And again if user click back button then go to previous activity.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) > 5
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
    //    if(recyclerview == onFirstPosition){
    //      goBack; }
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new 
LinearSmoothScroller(getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
            return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
        }
    };
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(0);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
            .getLayoutManager();
    layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}
```

Now i can scroll to top with this code but don't know how to go back if user is on first item.

Comment: check the first visible item of recyclerview and make a conditional statement according to that
Try findFirstVisibleItemPosition();   if this returns 0 then call super.onBackPressed() 
 method to exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First way

You  can use a `boolean` flag like below example

Take one `boolean isFirstTime=true;` variable

Try this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(isFirstTime){
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            isFirstTime=false;
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

> Second way

Using **`LinearLayoutManager`** check that the visible item in your screen is first item or not

**Example**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                .getLayoutManager();
        if(layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==0){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the first method you have to also reset the boolean if they scroll down again.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi didn't get u my friend

Comment: Check this scenario. I am down in the list i press the back button, i scroll to top in that case the boolean is set to false. Now i scroll back down and press the back button, the boolean is still false and i will exit the activity rather than scrolling up.

Comment: So i guess we have to use the on scroll method as well to reset the boolean back to true if i scroll down.

Comment: @SarthakGandhi yup in this case we need to reset that boolean flag

Comment: @SarthakGandhi but this case will not effect in second solution

Comment: Yes the second solution is perfect and short.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==0) {
        super.onBackPressed();           
    }else {
        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
    }
}
```